# Cov(X,Y) = f(Cov(X,Z), Cov(Y,Z)) ?

Tags: covariance

I was wondering if given 3 random vars X,Y,Z, assuming we know Cov(X,Z) and Cov(Y,Z), is there a formula to get Cov(X,Y) ?
Thank you !

Comment: I found a bunch of answers by searching this site for [covariance determinant positive](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=covariance+determinant+positive).